# Trying to use import/export in ES6 (with babel compile)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, babeljs

Here are the files for my app which uses babel to compile the ES6 in `main.js` to ES5 in `main.bundle.js`

[image]

Here is my `babel.rc` file (hidden):

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Here is my `package.json` file with all my node modules (devDependencies):

```
{
  "name": "es6-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ES6 tutorial",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "babel js/main.js -o build/main.bundle.js",
    "start": "http-server",
    "watch": "babel js/main.js -o build/main.bundle.js --watch"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1"
  }
}
```

Right now to start the compile from ES6 to ES5 I navigate (`cd`) to the root of this directory and I set up a watch to compile automatically (`npm run watch`)

This works fine except now I also have functions in `myFunctions.js` that I want to export and import into `main.js`

When I add this export/import I notice that the compiled file, `main.bundle.js`, adds this:

```
`var _myFunctions = require('myFunctions.js');`
```

Then when I go to run the app I get an error in the console:

```
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at main.bundle.js:9`
```

After researching this, I think I need to add some sort of plugin for Babel : https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#modules to handle the export/import (is that right?) but I'm not sure which one I should use and I tried a few but I cannot get any to work after the npm install.

Also, I understand that I do NOT need to add the `require.js` library right?

Comment: `npm run watch` can be anything, please post your package.json scripts section

Comment: I updated my post to show my package.json

Comment: You are transforming to es5, but not to browser environment. This module can help you https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-preset-env.html

Comment: I added that module (see my package.json above). However I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Do I need to update my `.babelrc`?

Comment: Webpack would be the way to go.

Comment: Yes of course, npm install is not enough, you need to tell babel what you want it to do

Comment: Still not able to get this to work ..updated by `babelrc` (above) and now I can't do `npm run babel`